# migrating from multiple csv files in one migration class

Tags: 7, migrations

I have multiple CSV files in different folders. 
The folder names are the node ids. And each folder contains its own CSV file.
Now I want to loop these directories and import from the CSV files in one migration class but it only migrate from the last CSV  file.

Here is my code

```
class MigrateNodes extends Migration {
  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct();
    $columns[0] = array('Number', 'Number');
    $columns[1] = array('Title', 'Title');
    $columns[2] = array('Description', 'Description');
    //The Description of the import. This desription is shown on the Migrate GUI
    $this->description = t('Import lots from excell file ');
    $nids = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('nid'))
        ->condition('n.type', 'type')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchCol();
    foreach ($nids as $nid) {
   $path = $nid . "/nodes.csv";
      //The Source of the import
      $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV($path', $columns, array('header_rows' => 1));
      if ($this->source) {
        $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('lot');
        $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap(
            $this->machineName, array(
          "Number" => array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'alias' => 'import'
          )
            ), MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
        );
        //Field ampping
        $this->addFieldMapping('title', 'Title');
        $this->addFieldMapping('field_lot_description', 'Description');
      //}
      }
   }
  }
}
```

The Number field is unique.
Any one knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it.
Just place the following line after the field mappings if it is the import process.

```
$this->processImport();
```

Comment: this is also covered in the Migrate Examples module. The baseball example uses multiple csv files as the datasource.